# meaning of 'sip'

Tags: word-meaning

> Two were an old ill-favored pair;
>
> But the third was young, and passing fair,
>
> With laughing eyes and with coal-black hair;
>
> A dainty quean was she!
>
> Rob would have given his ears to sip
>
> But a single salute from her cherry lip.

As far as I know 'to sip' is used when describing the act of drinking. But in this poem, it seems like 'to sip' means 'to listen'. Am I rightly understood?

Comment: We use the lips to sip. Do you think Rob might like to do something with the pretty girl's mouth, using his lips?

Comment: Remembering that this is poetry, and that we sip with our mouths, what kind of 'salute' would Rob like to sip from the young girl's own lip?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well put; my guess is the OP simply didn't realize the final line is a continuation of the sentence from the previous line.